# web crawling using R

Tags: r, dataset, web-crawler

i am trying to create a Data Set with crawling using R.
this is my code

```
ID <- "english-premier-league-transfers"
URL <- paste0("http://www.soccernews.com/soccer-transfers/", ID)
parsed.html <- htmlParse(URL)

targetPoint <-"//div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='league-transfers']/div[@class='panes']"
playersList <- xpathSApply(parsed.html, targetPoint , xmlValue)
```

the problem is that i am getting one big string, and i need a XML data set.
someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean precisely by "XML data set". If you want separate nodes you could try

```
playersList <- xpathSApply(parsed.html, targetPoint) # only xmlValue is missing
```

If you want to have the names and other details as separate strings, you could do this:

```
playersList <- xpathSApply(parsed.html, targetPoint, xmlChildren)
player.names <- sapply(playersList[,1], USE.NAMES = F, FUN = function (element) {
  xmlValue(element[[1]][[1]])
})
```

This gives you the names. If you want to get the other properties, play around with the indeces after `element`:

```
player.positions <- sapply(playersList[,1], USE.NAMES = F, FUN = function (element) {
  xmlValue(element[[1]][[3]])
})
```

`[[2]][[1]]`gives you the nationality, `[[3]][[1]]`gives you the "to"-team and so on...

EDIT: Of course, for example `data.frame(name = player.names, position = player.positions)` gives you a nice R data.frame of your crawled data. Also look out for potential copyright issues of this data!